# Passing a Smarty variable into Javascript link "src" attribute

Tags: javascript, smarty

I've assigned a Smarty variable:

```
{assign var="siteurl" value="http://website.com"}
```

I can successfully use it in my header.html file to call a CSS link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$siteurl}/style.css" />
```

displays

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://website.com/style.css" />
```

However, when I do the same for a Javascript source, it literally prints out "{$siteurl}":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$siteurl}/scripts.js"></script>
```

displays

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$siteurl}/scripts.js"></script>
```

Why isn't this Smarty variable displaying as expected?

Comment: Strange. It shouldn't do that all by itself. What version of Smarty is this? Are you using `{literal}{/literal}` somewhere?

Comment: You know what, I am themeing an aMember system.  So, I didn't build the system from scratch.  I bet they've put {literal} tags wrapping the content somewhere in the file structure.  Now that I know that the above code should work, I'll start going through the file structure for debug.  Thanks.  Is there a possible php function that they could've called (that I should look out for) to enable this {literal} functionality?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved!**
As mentioned in the comments above, I am working on an aMember system.  I'm not sure if they leave smarty {literal} tags open at the end of their initial files, and then close them at the end, or what.  But the fix was replacing

```
{$siteurl}
```

with

```
{/literal}{$siteurl}{literal}
```

I tried putting the reverse {literal} tags at the beginning and end of the document, but it threw an error.  I have to manually put the code above for each javascript src instance.

**THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE FOR THE HELP!!**

Comment: I've a similar situation here but little complex,look @ my code. `{literal}<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?client_id=2343434234&fb_on‌ ​ ly=true&redirect_uri=http://localhots/POC/manage_users.php?reg_type={/literal}{$regtype}{literal}&act_action=save_profiledata&fields=[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'gender'}, {'name':'location'}, {'name':'birthday'}]" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" style="border:none" allowTransparency="true" width="100%" height="360"></iframe>{/literal}` In this case it doesn't return full url but the value is retrieved.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are the script tags wrapped in a Smarty `{literal}{/literal}` block? That would prevent rendering of  the `{$siteurl}` tag.

Comment: No. I actually, tried wrapping them with {literal} while troubleshooting, but realized that it does the opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: You know what, I am themeing an aMember system.  So, I didn't build the system from scratch.  I bet they've put {literal} tags wrapping the content somewhere in the file structure.  Now that I know that the above code should work, I'll start going through the file structure for debug.  Thanks.  Is there a possible php function that they could've called (that I should look out for) to enable this {literal} functionality?

Comment: I tried putting {/literal} at the beginning of the script, and then {literal} at the end of the script.  In case the aMember system left the {literal} tag open in one of the initial files, and closed it in one of the final files (for whatever reason). It drew an error though, so dice there either.  Hmm...