# javascript and smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

how in javascript insert smarty variables ?

```
var info = {
us: 'User: {$UserName}',
ad: 'Address: {$Address}',
img: 'Image: {$URL}'
}
```

And now show: User: {$UserName}, how show values?

For example: User: Peter

Thanks

Comment: Likely duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525598/passing-a-smarty-variable-into-javascript-link-src-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code wrapped in a {literal} {/literal} block?  This would stop the variables from being filled in.